# How to play DTMF tones in android via headphone programatically?

Tags: android, security, dtmf

I am currently working on a car security system....

I need to produce DTMF tones via the headphones of the phone that makes an input to the external digital circuit. 
Is there any API to do this?
Canany one helpm....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Dtmf tones are standardized. You can look up the frequencies for each tone and generate them manually.

Answer (score 6):

I got the Answer....Its very simple....

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html

```
ToneGenerator dtmfGenerator = new ToneGenerator(0,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
dtmfGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 1000); // all types of tones are available...
dtmfGenerator.stopTone();
```